Angular ignores compiler options paths
I am trying to build an Angular application that uses xml2js however I am getting the following error:
$ ng build
⠦ Building...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "timers"

    node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js:36:25:
      36 │   setImmediate = require('timers').setImmediate;
         ╵                          ~~~~~~~~

  The package "timers" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

I have built the app without any problems previously, however I recently started to get this problem. I didn't change angular.json or tsconfig.app.json since then. Also, the app correctly works if I run the dev-server via ng serve and via ng serve -c production.
angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "<NDA_OMIT>": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/<NDA_OMIT>",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "fast-levenshtein"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "8kb",
                  "maximumError": "16kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "<NDA_OMIT>:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "<NDA_OMIT>:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "<NDA_OMIT>:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "sass",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}


tsconfig.app.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@angular/localize"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "timers": [
        "./node_modules/timers-browserify"
      ],
      "stream": [
        "./node_modules/stream-browserify"
      ],
      "environment": [
        "./src/environments/environment"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

ng version output
Angular CLI: 17.2.0
Node: 20.11.0
Package Manager: npm 10.4.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 17.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1702.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular      17.2.0
@angular-devkit/core               17.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics         17.2.0
@angular/cdk                       17.3.7
@angular/cli                       17.2.0
@angular/material                  17.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   17.3.7
@schematics/angular                17.2.0
rxjs                               7.8.1
typescript                         5.3.3
zone.js                            0.14.4


For some reason, installing timers fixes the issue. xml2js works perfectly fine even if that library doesn't provide setImmediate.

nice!!!!!!!!!!!

delete the package-lock.json file and the node_modules folder, execute npm install and rerun your app and look if it works.

Didn't work unfortunately

First of all recommend to update to one of the latest version of node.js since there are some recent CVEs.
v20.15.1 (LTE) or 22.4.1 (current) [early july 2024]
Second: bring all your angular packages to the same version: 17.3.8 or 18.1.0. I recommend angular 18.
You update all packages to the latest version by executing npm update in your project root folder. After that npm outdated should not show any entries.
Third: after all, delete your node_modules and your package-lock.json and execute a final npm install.
If nothing of that helps, let us know.

Just change the builder to @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser
and configure the other options accordingly for that. It will build fine.
Like the following in your angular.json
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
           "outputPath": "dist/app",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",

